# ffmpeg not working for URL input(directly like -i "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hfff52cf71f784d99ad93c73a334e7e37a/65x70.gif")

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video, images, gif

i've been facing issue with parsing URL input to ffmpeg executable. earlier i used to check the details for GIF such as FPS & resolution using "ffmpeg.exe"but now it has stopped working when given URL input.

---

**command used** - **.\ffmpeg -i https://explore.zoom.us/docs/image/Hybrid_Workforce_Animated_Hero_Banner.gif**

PS G:\Tools\ffmpeg-n4.4.1-win64-gpl-4.4\bin> .\ffmpeg -i https://explore.zoom.us/docs/image/Hybrid_Workforce_Animated_Hero_Banner.gif

**ffmpeg version n4.4.1-20211027** Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-frei0r --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20211027
libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100

**[tcp @ 000002d7a9f7bec0]** **Connection to tcp://explore.zoom.us:443 failed: Error number -138 occurred
https://explore.zoom.us/docs/image/Hybrid_Workforce_Animated_Hero_Banner.gif: Unknown error**

**previous output -**
Input #0, gif, from 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\4vS50yJcihr-Ec.gif':
Duration: 00:00:00.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 248 kb/s
Stream #0:0: **Video: gif**, bgra, **100x100**, **33.33 fps**, 33.33 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc

Please help

thanks
AB

Comment: That gif in particular doesn't seem to exist or was this just a example?

Comment: The following command works in my machine: `ffmpeg -y -i https://explore.zoom.us/docs/image/Hybrid_Workforce_Animated_Hero_Banner.gif -c copy tmp.gif`

Comment: what's your ffmpeg version and output for above GIF? for me it is still not working

Comment: @RicardoBohner you can use the other given GIF example. I guess, title GIF link isn't working

Comment: With the second link it seems to work fine for me too. Maybe updating your ffmpeg version....